# How do I give all the right credit to the Harry Potter company and John Williams if I create a variation on the theme song?

Tags: copyright, music

I want to know how do I give all the right credit to the Harry Potter company and John Williams if I create a variation on the theme song for it and if I plan to sell it. I don't want to be sued by them but I want to sell them for 69c. Should I get rid of them from my rework album, because the rest of the variations are of classics in the public domain such as Für Elise.

Comment: If you give them all the rights, that includes the rights to the 69c. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Harry Potter company and John Williams may or may not want credit, but they almost certainly want money. You have to get their permission, at least for *their* creations. In the case of  Für Elise, you can freely use the original score to "rework" that piece, but you can't "rework" a version that is itself a recent "reworking" (known as a derivative work). Anything that Jon Williams created is protected by copyright, so you need to negotiate a license to create a derivative work, and he/they get to dictate the terms (like, half of the 69 cents per copy). That might include some attribution statement such as "with permission, copyright Warner Brothers", or whatever is stipulated in the license agreement.